# Download can't finish when I use StreamingHttpResponse in Django

Tags: python, docker, google-cloud-run

I'm using Django on Google cloud run. Download file page has not worked since when I updated docker image. Download file page program is below.

```
def file_iterator(file, chunk_size=512):
    with open(file, 'rb') as f:
        while True:
            c = f.read(chunk_size)
            if c:
                yield c
            else:
                break

def download_view(request, format, pk):
    user = get_user(request)
    sentence = Sentence.objects.get(pk=pk)
    if not default_storage.exists(sentence.file.name):
        logger.warning(f'This file has been deleted pk: {pk} user: {user} file_name:{sentence.file.name}')
        raise Http404()
    
    file_name = f'{user.pk}{sentence.pk}.{format}'
    file_path = sentence.file.name
    if format == 'mp3':
        with open(file_path,'wb') as f:
            f.write(sentence.file.read())
    elif format == 'wav':
        file_path = AudioSplitter().mp3_to_wav(sentence)
    else:
        return HttpResponse('format error')
    
    response = StreamingHttpResponse(file_iterator(file_path))
    response['Content-Type'] = 'audio/mpeg' if format == 'mp3' else 'audio/wav'
    response['Content-Disposition'] = f'attachment;filename="{file_name}"'
    return response
```

Google cloud run has download file limit. So this program using StreamingHttpResponse. It's return chunked file data. When I download file from this view, Download is stacked around 200 ~ 224KB.
[image]

This problem occurred  at 17 Aug 2021. I builded 3 images on the day.

1. 2021/08/17 10:24
2. 2021/08/17 15:54
3. 2021/08/17 20:58

1st container can download files. However 2nd and 3rd container can't download files from the view. And also all builded container can't download files after 1st container.

### What is difference between 1st and 2nd container?

I changed a line in `admin.py` It just added  `list_display_links = None`.

I checked python modules versions and python version. However it was same.

When I run `docker images`, I found that image size is different.

```
REPOSITOR              TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED          SIZE
gcr.io/***/***       8f6ae66   62d086d8f30c   7 weeks ago      2.07GB <-- 1st
gcr.io/***/***       bdf4a43   f67948780215   7 weeks ago      2.39GB <-- 2nd
```

1st container is 2.07GB and 2nd container is 2.39GB. My dockerfile is using `FROM python:3.9`. Has some updated on python3.9 image in 17 Aug??

I builded same code with 1st image. Naturally, This image has download page problem and container size was 2.28GB. It is bigger than 1st image. Python module has some difference and python version has updated to python 3.9.7.

I think this problem from docker image of python. How can I solve this problem?

### Update

1. I changed the image to `python: 3.8`. The problem has been reproduced.
2. I found this error when download was stacked. `uwsgi_response_write_body_do() TIMEOUT !!!`

**Environment**

1st and 2nd images environment.

- version: nginx/1.14.2
- uWSGI==2.0.19.1

```
# nginx-app.conf

# the upstream component nginx needs to connect to
upstream django {
    server unix:/code/app.sock; # for a file socket
    # server 127.0.0.1:8001; # for a web port socket (we'll use this first)
}

# configuration of the server
server {
    # the port your site will be served on, default_server indicates that this server block
    # is the block to use if no blocks match the server_name
    listen      8080;

    # the domain name it will serve for
    server_name xxx.com; # substitute your machine's IP address or FQDN
    charset     utf-8;

    # max upload size
    client_max_body_size 10M;   # adjust to taste
    # set timeout
    uwsgi_read_timeout 900;
    proxy_read_timeout 900;
    # Django media
    location /media  {
        alias /code/app/media;  # your Django project's media files - amend as required
    }

    location /static {
        alias /code/app/static; # your Django project's static files - amend as required
    }

    # Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include     /code/uwsgi_params; # the uwsgi_params file you installed
    }
}
```

```
[uwsgi]
# this config will be loaded if nothing specific is specified
# load base config from below
ini = :base

# %d is the dir this configuration file is in
socket = %dapp.sock
master = true
processes = 4
max-requests = 1000                  ; Restart workers after this many requests
max-worker-lifetime = 3600           ; Restart workers after this many seconds
reload-on-rss = 512                  ; Restart workers after this much resident memory
worker-reload-mercy = 60             ; How long to wait before forcefully killing workers
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem. I think It was coursed by this error.

`uwsgi_response_write_body_do() TIMEOUT !!!`

I add sleep and change chunk size.

```
# change chunk size from 512 byte to 1 MB, because it sleep 0.1 sec each loop.

def file_iterator(file, chunk_size=1024 * 1024):
    with open(file, 'rb') as f:
        while True:
            time.sleep(0.1) # <-- add sleep
            c = f.read(chunk_size)
            if c:
                yield c
            else:
                break
```

P.S. I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48576866/5132860). But It dose not effect for me.

### Update

When I check myself to download. It's works fine. However request latency is very slow. around 15~18 minutes. When I run 1st image, it was around 0.2 ~ 0.3 seconds. And also Charged container instance time increased as 5 times.

#### 1 hour

[image]

#### 1 day

[image]

I feel this solution is first aid. I hole some one answer real solution.

### Update 2021/11/02

I found real solution! uWSGI socket connection has some problem. I changed PORT connection. Now my application return result very normal time.

[This is my settings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69807795/5132860)

Note: It's normal uWSGI PORT connection settings.