# How to fix 504 error caused by Docker image update

Tags: django, docker, nginx, uwsgi, google-cloud-run

I have Django project. It works with nginx, uwsgi and google cloud run.
This project is using docker which python:3.9 image. I have got this error since 17,Aug.

`2021-10-13 17:22:29.654 JSTGET504717 B899.9 sGoogleStackdriverMonitoring-UptimeChecks(https://cloud.google.com/monitoring) https://xxxx/`

`The request has been terminated because it has reached the maximum request timeout. To change this limit, see https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/request-timeout`

and also this error occur on all my pages. However when I open my pages myself, I can see my pages. It means I can't see 504 error and I can only check that it happens from server log.

[image]

I added a line in admin.py at 17, Aug. I didn't think this line is no related with this error. Because this change is only effect in admin page. I had rollback my code before the error. Now I'm still can't fix this error.

Builded docker image is different size before after error. And Vulnerability has decreased. I think this is caused by some small change on python image. In this case, how can I solve this problem?

[image]

### What I did

I changed docker image to python:3.8 and python:3.9.6-buster. I couldn't fix the error.

Comment: Well, 504 is a timeout. Is it possible that your data has grown enough that you're e.g. making tons of queries that you hadn't been making before?

Comment: Either way: look at the actual logs from the container!

Comment: Can you please provide us with the container logs as @AKX mentioned?

Comment: Sorry for late replay. How to get container logs from Google cloud run's running instance? I can see only Stackdriver log.

Comment: Usually ,I can see stack trace log when application stoped some error. However this timeout error does not show error logs. Do I need some settings in my Django app or Cloud run?

Comment: Please send your application logs to stack driver. Please check the [following article](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/logging#run_manual_logging-python) regarding how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem. I changed socket to port connection.

This is my settings.

**uwsgi.ini**

```
[uwsgi]
# this config will be loaded if nothing specific is specified
# load base config from below
ini = :base

# %d is the dir this configuration file is in
http = 127.0.0.1:8000
master = true
processes = 4
max-requests = 1000                  ; Restart workers after this many requests
max-worker-lifetime = 3600           ; Restart workers after this many seconds
reload-on-rss = 512                  ; Restart workers after this much resident memory
threaded-logger = true

[dev]
ini = :base
# socket (uwsgi) is not the same as http, nor http-socket
socket = :8001


[local]
ini = :base
http = :8000
# set the virtual env to use
home = /Users/you/envs/env


[base]
# chdir to the folder of this config file, plus app/website
chdir = %dapp/
# load the module from wsgi.py, it is a python path from 
# the directory above.
module = website.wsgi:application
# allow anyone to connect to the socket. This is very permissive
chmod-socket = 666
```

**nginx-app.conf**

```
# the upstream component nginx needs to connect to
upstream django {
    # server unix:/code/app.sock; # for a file socket
    server 127.0.0.1:8000; # for a web port socket (we'll use this first)
}

# configuration of the server
server {
    # the port your site will be served on, default_server indicates that this server block
    # is the block to use if no blocks match the server_name
    listen      8080;

    # the domain name it will serve for
    server_name MY_DOMAIN.COM; # substitute your machine's IP address or FQDN
    charset     utf-8;


    # max upload size
    client_max_body_size 10M;   # adjust to taste
    # set timeout
    uwsgi_read_timeout 900;
    proxy_read_timeout 900;
    # Django media
    location /media  {
        alias /code/app/media;  # your Django project's media files - amend as required
    }

    location /static {
        alias /code/app/static; # your Django project's static files - amend as required
    }

    # Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        include     /code/uwsgi_params; # the uwsgi_params file you installed
    }
}
```